# Specific user type in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have 3 files for connection.php. work.php login.php
  these are the codes that I use to be able to identify the users type or the   type      of administrator in the database.

I use MySQL since it is required in the coding/dev process,

The problem that I am encountering is that I am unable to detect the user    type. 
   Can you please suggest what could be the possible to identify the user types.

[image]
    login.php

```
<?php
// Try and connect to the database
include('connection.php');
$selected = mysql_select_db("wildlife",$conn)
  or die("Could not select ");

   //$myusername =    mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
   //$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
            $user = $_POST['user'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            //$type = $_POST['type'];

            // $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass'      
            //and  emp_type = '1'");


            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username='$user' and  emp_password='$pass' ");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
            { 
                //check if there is already an entry for that username
                echo "<br>DETECTED Username AND PASS already exists!";
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT emp_type FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_type = '1' ");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
                    { 
                    //check if there is already an entry for that username
                        echo "<br>KING1";

                    }
                else
                    {

                        echo "<br>QUEEN1";
                    }

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT emp_type FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_type = '2' ");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
                    { 
                    //check if there is already an entry for that username
                        echo "<br>KING2";

                    }
                else
                    {

                        echo "<br>QUEEN";
                    }
            }
            else
            {

                //header("location:index.php");
                echo(" No User Found");
                //header('work.php');
            }
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'wildlife');

    if (!$conn) 
    {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysql_errno());
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("connected from connection.php");
    }
?>
```

work.php

```
<?php
include('login.php');
?>

<html>
<head><title>INDETIFY THE USER TYPE</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post"> <!-- Sign In Process -->
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="emp_username"style="width:150">
<br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="emp_password"style="width:153">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

as a result the when **super , super ** is entered

[image]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection! What if the user passes in malicious data into $_POST['user']? Don't use the mysql_ functions but instead consider using mysqli_ or PDO with binded parameters.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: You can remove duplicate code by using the OR statement in your query: ```WHERE emp_type = '2' OR emp_type='1' ```

Comment: You select ALL the columns from `wrd_users` in the first query and then in the second reselect just one field. Not efficient, you already have `emp_type` returned in the first query.

Comment: @user1 Data already there from first query. The whole second query is unnecessary

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text!!!! Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: The only real answer here is pay more attention is class or find and read a good book on programming and PHP and Database and MYSQL

Comment: I solved it by using PHP SESSION .

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. Related question: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO database extension to connect to a MySQL-Database.

Second: Your implementation is wrong. Your functions `mysql_num_rows` will always return exactly one row, because all you said in the query was "give me all rows where `emp_type` is 1" (or 2). But this will always return one row, because you have that row with emp_type 1.
Edit your query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_type FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username = '$user'");
```

After that, you can read what's in the `emp_type` record of your result.

An even better method would be to escape your entered information to prevent sql-injection:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_type FROM wrd_users WHERE emp_username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'");
```

But remember **not** to use mysql_* anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM wrd_users 
                      WHERE emp_username='$user' 
                        and  emp_password='$pass' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) 
{ 
    //check if there is already an entry for that username

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if($row['emp_type']=='1')
    {
        echo "<br>KING1";
    }

    if($row['emp_type']=='2')
    {
        echo "<br>KING2";
    }                      
}
else
{

    //header("location:index.php");
    echo(" No User Found");
    //header('work.php');
}
```

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy